# Компиляция .exe из Python программы

Tags: python-3.x, json

Пытался скомпилировать .py программу для перевода сленговых слов, но после компиляции в .exe, сам исполняемый файл просто открывался и сразу закрывался.
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему [ссылка на программу](https://bitbucket.org/xu33u/homework/downloads/)
Программа работает при запуске из интерпретатора.

```py
import json
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from perevod import *

from difflib import get_close_matches


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.btnResult.clicked.connect(self.getResult)

    def getResult(self):
        n1 = self.ui.txtNum1.toPlainText()

        output = retrive_definition(n1)

        if type(output) == list:
            for item in output:
                print("-item",item)
                out = item
        else:
            print("-output",output)
            out = output

        self.ui.lblSum.setPlainText(out)

    def mbox(self, body, title='Error'):
        dialog = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, title, body)
        dialog.exec_()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def retrive_definition(word):
    word = word.lower()

    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif word.title() in data:
        return data[word.title()]
    elif word.upper() in data:
        return data[word.upper()]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        action = input("Может быть Вы имели в виду %s ? [да или нет]: " % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        if action == "да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Да":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif action == "Нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        elif action == "нет":
            return "Слово пока не существует в словаре."
        else:
            return "Я не понимаю вашу запись. Извините."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
41 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
41 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
42 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
43 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\translator.spec
44 INFO: UPX is not available.
45 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Xu33u\\PycharmProjects\\homework',
 'C:\\Users\\Xu33u\\PycharmProjects\\homework']
45 INFO: checking Analysis
45 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
45 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
46 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
48 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2340 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2341 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by d:\python37\python.exe
2373 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python.exe
2399 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python.exe
2424 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python.exe
2449 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python.exe
2476 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python.exe
2520 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2545 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2570 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2594 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2620 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2645 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2669 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2694 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2719 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2744 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2768 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2794 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\python37.dll
2825 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2850 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2875 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2900 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2925 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2926 INFO: Caching module hooks...
2932 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\homework.py
2963 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2963 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
3026 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
3026 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3206 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3207 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3212 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3247 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3272 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3301 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3325 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3350 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3374 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3398 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3427 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3451 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3476 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3506 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3534 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3559 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3583 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3608 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3632 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3661 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
3685 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
3715 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\_socket.pyd
3746 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\select.pyd
3798 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3823 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3847 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3871 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3895 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3921 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3945 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3970 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
3994 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4018 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libcrypto-1_1.dll
4050 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
4074 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
4100 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
4124 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of d:\python37\DLLs\libssl-1_1.dll
4124 INFO: Looking for eggs
4125 INFO: Using Python library d:\python37\python37.dll
4125 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
4133 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\build\translator\warn-translator.txt
4166 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\build\translator\xref-translator.html
4177 INFO: checking PYZ
4177 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
4177 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\build\translator\PYZ-00.pyz
4621 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\build\translator\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
4628 INFO: checking PKG
4628 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
4628 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
5675 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
5677 INFO: Bootloader d:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
5677 INFO: checking EXE
5677 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
5678 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
5678 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Xu33u\PycharmProjects\homework\dist\translator.exe
5749 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92877/discussion-on-question-by-vladislav--exe--python-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2013. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\ALEX>cd C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework

C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework>pyinstaller homework.py --onefile -- 
icon="C:\Us
ers\ALEX\Downloads\homework\icon.ico"
160 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
160 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
161 INFO: Platform: Windows-8.1-6.3.9600-SP0
322 INFO: wrote C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\homework.spec
326 INFO: UPX is not available.
352 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\ALEX\\Downloads\\homework', 
'C:\\Users\\ALEX\\Downloads\\homework']

354 INFO: checking Analysis
354 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
354 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
360 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
366 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
8461 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
8507 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of 
final executable required by c:\python37\python.exe
9134 INFO: Caching module hooks...
9151 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\homework.py
9376 INFO: Loading module hooks...
9377 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
9543 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
9545 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
9842 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
10059 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
10617 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
11161 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
11744 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
11745 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
11753 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
11766 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
12917 WARNING: lib not found: python35.dll dependency of c:\python37\lib\site- 
packages\sip.pyd
13918 INFO: Looking for eggs
13919 INFO: Using Python library c:\python37\python37.dll
13919 INFO: Found binding redirects:[]
13992 INFO: Warnings written to 
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\build\homework\
warn-homework.txt
14102 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to 
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\bu
ild\homework\xref-homework.html
14296 INFO: checking PYZ
14296 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
14298 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\build\ho
mework\PYZ-00.pyz
16281 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) 
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\build\ho
mework\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
16307 INFO: checking PKG
16307 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
16309 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
16947 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
16947 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
'C:\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
'BINARY')
16949 WARNING: was placed previously at
16951 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
'C:\\python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
'BINARY')
31716 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
31786 INFO: Bootloader c:\python37\lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Wind
ows-32bit\run.exe
31786 INFO: checking EXE
31786 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
31786 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
32248 INFO: SRCPATH [('C:\\Users\\ALEX\\Downloads\\homework\\icon.ico', None)]
32248 INFO: Updating icons from 
['C:\\Users\\ALEX\\Downloads\\homework\\icon.ico
'] to C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2qxjxaqz
32288 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes
32288 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 67624 bytes
32448 INFO: Appending archive to EXE 
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework\dist\homework.exe
33388 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
C:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\homework>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[ссылка на скачивание архива там 2 exe один с консолью другой нет](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-B90QZF-91suyCpeVvgLKGxXxFIszjl2)

Comment: Переустановил, но все равно ничего не вышло. Вот [ссылка на имгур с папкой Python'ом](https://imgur.com/a/dG9ZNYz)

Comment: Установите вот так C:/Python37 И скачайте версию 3.7.0 и там заново через pip установите модули не забудьте удалить предыдущею версию

Comment: При установке всё по умолчанию кроме пути

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, все равно насыпало варнингов +- как в прошлые разы и отказалось работать. Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, скинуть уже скомпилированный .exe-файл ? Завтра защита проекта, боюсь, что сам уже не успею разобраться во всем этом.

Comment: Хорошо только вы мне data.json в кодировке utf-8 залейте

Comment: А то так не будет работать

Comment: Вот [data.json](https://dropmefiles.com/1hiWV)

Comment: Если ещё актуально то я обновил ответ там ссылка на exe.